# How to get autocomplete feature for cocos2d-x on eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, autocomplete, cocos2d-x

This is quite a beginner question, but I have been working on cocos2d-iPhone for quite some time on xcode. Now I have switched to cocos2d-x on eclipse, and I am very used to the autocomplete feature. Eclipse does not give autocompletes on pressing ctrl+space for cocos2d-x data types and functions. Is their anyway to get those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @user2228947 said, Eclipse can't find the cocos2d-x headers, we need to link the cocos2d-x  with our project. I had followed the below steps to enable Auto completion:

> 1. Right click on the project and click on 'Properties'.
> 2. Navigate to C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Source Location.
> 3. Click **'Link Folder'**  and then check on 'Link to folder in File
>      system' checkbox.
> 4. Now 'Browse' to the **"${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx"** folder and click 'ok'

Source: [Cocos2d-x Forum](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/18/topics/20276?r=24527#message-24527)

Comment: If this doesn't work you might also want to consider going to C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Includes and under the GNU C++ language include your ${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx and ${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/include folders.

Comment: err, I can't seem to find the folder indicated here in CC2dx version 3.x

Comment: This may not work directly for v3.11.1. But main idea is to include folders which has .h files. So, include cocos2d and cocos2d/cocos folders to make it work. \Also.. in C++General ->preprocessor Include Paths -> Tick CDT Builtin Compiler Settings and CDT CROSS GCC Builtin Compiler Settings. Also, fix path in Project properties - >Resources->Linked Resources ->(Tab Linked Resources) -> Cocos2d path may be wrong.. So fix that path, you may also use ${PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC} for fixing that path.

Answer (score -1):

Probably it cannot find cocos2d headers in include paths.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. You can improve it by adding additional information that would help solve the problem, such as how to include the headers.